# How to feed Antlr goal from local maven repository?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, antlr4, offline-caching

I am trying to build my project on an offline machine (this is a requirement). I have created local maven repository (it's just a folder with appropriate structure) and successfully build all other things.

I do the following way:

1) Run `gradle installl` (this maven plugin's goal)

then checking errors by hand. If I see some library not found, then

2) I take it's maven coordinates and copy in to this machine by hand from my machine.

It works except of Antlr. I getting the following message:

```
>gradle install
:generateGrammarSource

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':antlr'.
> Could not download antlr4.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.5)
   > Could not get resource 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5/antlr4-4.5.jar'
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5/antlr4-4.5.jar'.
         > Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
```

error message is the same as always, but this time putting jar into local maven repository does not help.

How to overcome? How to configure Antlr to eat from local maven repo?

**UPDATE**

File is present in

```
 MYHOME\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.antlr\antlr4\4.5\af4a530e3cd7fa03636645d8077145eefac12907\antlr4-4.5.jar
```

and in

```
MYHOME\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4\4.5\antlr4-4.5.jar
```

In maven case accompaning files are also present.

**UPDATE 2**

Note that it says

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':antlr'.
```

and Antlr dependency is added by

```
antlr "org.antlr:antlr4:4.5" // use ANTLR version 4
```

i.e. not `compile` and not `testCompile`. May be this is the clue? May be it is a way to configure repositores specifically to `antlr` configuration?

**UPDATE 3**

I those cases I was resolving successfully it was writing:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not resolve net.coobird:thumbnailator:0.4.8.
  Required by:
      com.cireca.overlaywidget:OverlayWidget:1.0-SNAPSHOT
   > Could not resolve net.coobird:thumbnailator:0.4.8.
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/coobird/thumbnailator/0.4.8/thumbnailator-0.4.8.pom'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/coobird/thumbnailator/0.4.8/thumbnailator-0.4.8.pom'.
            > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
```

**UPDATE 4**

Strange thing. I noticed that my config looks redundant:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven" }
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }

    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven" }

}
```

I changed this to

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }

    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven" }

}
```

And after that it started to claim different liraries. First it claimed

```
org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5
```

and I fed it successfully, but then it claimed

```
org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.5.2
```

and I can't feed it (same situation).

Comment: Show the structure in your repo

Comment: Why it displays `Could not download antlr4.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.5)` wheres is should try to download `antlr4-4.5.jar`?

Comment: I can't duplicate it, it works on my workstation.

Comment: @Opal where did you see it can't download `antlr4.jar`? It can't download `org.antlr:antlr4:4.5`, which are maven coordinates. Corresponding JAR name is `antlr4-4.5.jar`.

Comment: Here: `Could not download antlr4.jar (org.antlr:antlr4:4.5)`

Comment: @Opal ah, yes true, strange

Comment: Could you please provide a `build.gradle` that reproduces the problem? I see you have `antlr` configuration defined e.g.

Comment: Also, please run `gradle dependencies` and investigate if antlr dependency you defined is not substituted by an another version.

Comment: @Opal Antlr dependencies looks ok in `gradle dependencies`, but I have failed dependency there `--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 20.0 FAILED` which I can't satisfy with my mirror technique (both 19th and 20th guava are in the local repo).

Answer (score 0):

Maven contacts the repositories as specified in your settings.xml. If you want to avoid external repositories, you need to mirror everything.

Actually, the best approach to work in environment not connected to the internet is to set up your own Nexus/Artifactory. And the easiest way to fill up your repository for offline use to connect it to the internet once, then build everything and disconnect. Then you have a local copy of everything that is relevant for you.

Comment: I am mirroring everything. But in case of antlr it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed remote repositories references completely from that machine (before this the remote repositories just had lower priority).

After that the Gradle started to report what it miss in the form of explicit local paths and I found, that it had lack of some parent (?) artifacts.

For example, for Guava, it was wishing `com.google.guava:guava-parent` and for antlr it was `org.antlr:antlr-master`. These names were not reported when remote repositories were present in the config.

If anybody could explain what happened in more detailed way, I will accept his/her answer.